# Cleaning up data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very long range of dates/times in Excel.

The raw data looks like this:

[image: The raw data looks like this]

I would like to sort the data so that column A is represented with every date (even if it isn't in the data) and column B with the amount for that date.

The result should look something like this:

[image: The result should look something like this]

I'm sure this can be done using a formula?

Comment: What excel version? In office 365 you could use `UNIQUE` for column 1 and `COUNTIF` for the second column.

Comment: Or a pivot table with rows grouped by day and a count for the rows. https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/grouped-date-field-formatting/

Comment: Do you know you can find the date out of a datetime using the formula `=ROUNDDOWN(A2,0)`?

Comment: You write *"colunm A is represented with every date (even if it isn't in the data)"*.  What does ***every date*** mean?   Do you want all 10,000 dates that Excel can represent as a date?  Or some smaller number of dates.

Comment: So even though the date range in the example only is 5, 7, 11 and 12. I would like the new range to display 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 etc.
But the dates with no entries should display 0

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen You should be more specific.  `1` represents `1-Jan-1900` and etc could concievably go up to `31-Dec-9999`. How, specifically, are you setting the bounds?  Once you do that, it is a simple matter to create a column of the necessary dates, then merely use COUNTIF to ascertain how many times those dates exist.  Please **edit your question** to show what you have tried, and to provide the additional detail.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I disagree, no qualms with this question - why limit yourself to the end of the Gregorian calendar- go to the end of time if you will, this has zero impact upon the exposure profile which is the crux of the question and it should *go without saying* that all dates refers to dates between the first and last date on record given this premise.  Including 0 counts for a bunch of exposure days before and after shouldn't even feature as a consideration upon which massive confusion should arise.  I'm saying this with respect but forcibly as it is a std. / basic time-series Q.

Comment: @JB-007 In the general sense you are correct, of course. However, in the context of **this** forum, the absence of any research effort, and the multiple questions asked, prompted my question to encourage the OP to begin thinking critically about how to set up a solution, instead of just supplying one.  I imagine the down-vote was related to the lack of any research effort shown in the question.

Comment: @JB-007 So far as your "*goes without saying*" date range, I disagree since the desired output shows dates outside of the range from first to last.

Comment: @RonRosenfield - unnecessary detail - it's clear there is 0 count/exposure beyond the base period of analysis - anything else borders on being pedantic - it was clear to me.

Comment: I don't mean to call you out - I'm just standing ground for something I don't think should've been disputed - I'm being frank.  Trust in order.

Comment: Be practical - let the user specify beginning and end dates if you feel it's a must have - in the end it wouldn't make a difference and putting "max (date)+" to signify any date after the last observed date, with count =0, and likewise "min(date)-"  with count=0 for exposure prior to earliest date would suffice I dare say.

Comment: @JB-007 Our disagreement seems related to the idea of providing the OP a solution (with some explanation, to be sure); vs encouraging the OP to think about how to create a solution on their own.  I don't think any more needs to be said.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Fair enough - we agree to disagree it seems :)

Answer (score -1):

Screenshot(s)/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gYdb-pJ7JZIeVddY-A?e=MCsl6d) refer:

*(link above is for Edited version - see details below)*

You have two questions:

- Q1: how to construct sequential data based upon raw non-sequential dates
- Q2: how to obtain corresponding frequencies/exposures for (1) in relation to raw underlying dates

### Q1

This is a common question for time-series analysis (i.e. construction of sequential 'dummy' data - certainly not one that requires static nature of pivots etc.

Here's how I generally go about this:

1] Obtain minimum of data in first cell/row:

[image: Initialise sequential dates]

```
=MIN(B2:B59)
```

---

**EDITED**: **given timestamps exist in raw data, you'll want to eliminate these for construction of time-series data - can do as follows:**

[image: Eliminating timestamps (day begins 00h00)]

```
=LET(r_1,MIN(B2:B59),DATE(YEAR(r_1),MONTH(r_1),DAY(r_1)))
```

**Remainder of this solution (Q1) remains unchanged...**

---

2] Next, create sequential data up to the maximum date as follows:

[image: Implement sequential design with desired periodicity (daily)]

```
=IFERROR(IF(E2+1>MAX($B$2:$B$59),"",E2+1),"")
```

3] Drag the formula (2) down the cells until they turn blank (days difference between max and min dates in your raw data should correspond to number of rows of sequential daily dates)

If you wanted a periodicity of 12 hours (e.g. AM/PM), you'd simply add 12/24 to each preceding date in step 2 (instead of 1 as we have here)

This concludes construction of dummy time series data.

---

### Q2:

To address this, I use an array which is particularly useful (but not essential) feature of Office 365 compatible version of Excel (due to easy referencing later in relation to 'spill' functions.

Notwithstanding, you can construct an array formula just as easily in older Excel versions by selecting the desired output range, entering the formula, and pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter (simultaneously instead of 'hotkey' style'.  Trust you are already aware...

*Method 1* - manual calculation:

[image: Exposure/Frequency array]

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B59,E2:E1123)
```

---

**EDITED**: **given timestamps exist in raw data, you'll need to circumvent as follows:
Enter 0 in first row (unless earliest date was exactly at 00h00, unlikely, but worth checking if you must)**

**Enter following array for subsequent time-series dates:**

[image: EDITED: Manual calc: to allow for time-stamps in raw data]

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B59,"<"&E2:E1123+1,B2:B59,">="&E2:E1123)
```

**Remainder of the steps (incl. validation section) remain unchanged and produce identical correspondence as we had before. Excel's Frequency function is smart enough to see no exposure corresponds to first date in time-series synthetic data...**

---

*Method 2* - Excel's native 'frequency' function:

[image: Frequency function]

```
=FREQUENCY(B2:B59,E2:E1123)
```

---

**EDITED**: **frequency function (using edited time-series defn. above, produces an identical summary of exposures (vs. edited manual approach using `countifs`, above) - and yep, *still*  comforting to see exact correspondence between this new time-series data and raw underlying dates RE: exposure ☺**

[image: Exact correspondence, and validation / recon in tact after allowing for timestamps]

---

Notes: Array need not be used with method 1 (you'd just need to bullet/fix cell references with $ signs and drag the appropriate function down the cells as req.).

Method 2 requires an array by default.

---

**Validation**

Of course, we can see the manually constructed and native 'frequency' functions produce identical data.

To close - a quick check against the raw data would be purposeful: summing exposures corresponding to time-series data (Q1) should reconcile to the count of dates / rows in the underlying raw / non-sequential data/dates:

[image: Reconciling exposure: synthesised time-series vs. raw exposure data]

```
=SUM(F2#)-COUNTA(B2:B59)
```

(you'll have to select the data in col F manually if you're not using Office 365 compatible Excel)

Comforting to see this calculation demonstrates identical exposure between both sets: ☺

---

Comment: PS - for all those questioning OPs question - I have following comment: kindly see that it would be pointless to fill in incremental dates beyond/prior to first and last day given you could hypothetically continue in this vein until the end of time, and then spend the rest of your days in the next multiverse assigning 0 counts next to each -  with no impact / effect or material gain in information..  It would be a terrible waste of substantive time and if you *really* have to just write "last date +" and "first date -" and put 0 counts next to each (will save you generations of time!). Peace